# How can I convert information represented on a json forma to a table or diagram in an android application

Tags: android

I want to know how I can read information from a database to an android application. This information should be represented on a diagram. Now I can read my information but in json format?

Comment: This question may help you : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8366911/populating-table-layout-using-json-string

Comment: Can you share the code you have tried so far?